# Why do some register functions generated by svd2rust use unsafe while others do not?

Tags: rust, embedded

I am inspecting the use of Rust code in embedded systems in order to understand the use of unsafe in libraries.

Specifically, I looked at the `stm32f30x` library that is generated by `svd2rust`. When I look at the functions that are associated with the `afrh` and `moder` registers of the `GPIOA` peripheral, the setting of bit values of the `afrh` register's fields requires unsafe code while it is not needed for the `moder` register's fields.

This is the code extracted from [afrh_register_functions](https://github.com/japaric/stm32f30x/tree/master/src/gpioa/afrh/mod.rs) and [moder_register_functions](https://github.com/japaric/stm32f30x/tree/master/src/gpioa/moder/mod.rs)

*for afrh register*

```rust
pub unsafe fn bits(self, value: u8) -> &'a mut W {
    const MASK: u8 = 15;
    const OFFSET: u8 = 28;
    self.w.bits &= !((MASK as u32) << OFFSET);
    self.w.bits |= ((value & MASK) as u32) << OFFSET;
    self.w
}
```

*for moder register*

```rust
pub fn bits(self, value: u8) -> &'a mut W {
    const MASK: u8 = 3;
    const OFFSET: u8 = 22;
    self.w.bits &= !((MASK as u32) << OFFSET);
    self.w.bits |= ((value & MASK) as u32) << OFFSET;
    self.w
}
```

Comment: Edit the code to remove the `unsafe`, then compile it. The compiler is your friend in static languages like Rust and it will point you to what needs the `unsafe` or that there's unneeded unsafe elsewhere. My **guess** is that the `unsafe` isn't needed and you can submit a PR removing it.

Comment: Auto-generated code is prone to having inconsistencies like this, particularly as it comes from a really, *really* loose definition for what the registers can and cannot do (SVD). The reason the `unsafe` is there might be because of one such feature of it.

Answer (score 1):

Peeking into the [codebase](https://github.com/rust-embedded/svd2rust/blob/master/src/generate/register.rs) for `svd2rust`, I found the function [`unsafety`](https://github.com/rust-embedded/svd2rust/blob/master/src/generate/register.rs#L583) which appears to determine whether or not insert the `unsafe` keyword into the generated code.

It looks as though it is trying to determine from the SVD file whether it is safe to write any value of the given size into the given register. This makes sense - sometimes registers have certain bit combinations that should not be used or might have undefined results.

Note that the `unsafe` keyword here is applied to the function. According to the rust book:

> The unsafe keyword in this context indicates the function has
>   requirements we need to uphold when we call this function, because
>   Rust can’t guarantee we’ve met these requirements. By calling an
>   unsafe function within an unsafe block, we’re saying that we’ve read
>   this function’s documentation and take responsibility for upholding
>   the function’s contracts.

So, the rust code itself may not be unsafe, but calling it could be depending on the supplied arguments.

I took a look at the svd file for the `stm32f30x` and I could not see how `svd2rust` came to this conclusion, perhaps someone else can enlighten us there.

Comment: I think you are right. They may have enumerated the values for some registers by editing the svd file and then generated the code: This makes sense : https://github.com/rust-embedded/svd2rust/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L332